# Function called by the control flow, not by tkinter bind

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a following function

```
def insert_word(listbox,text):
    t_start.insert(INSERT, text)
    print "worked"
```

binded to "< Return >" key via

```
listbox.bind("<Return>", insert_word(t_start,listbox.get(ACTIVE)))
```

Why the function is being called when the control flow comes, not when I press Return?
What's the entire idea behind bind function if it can be triggered somehow else then the bind itself?

Would I need a class with `__init__` and `__call__` methods to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is called because *you are actually calling it*.

```
listbox.bind("<Return>", insert_word(t_start,listbox.get(ACTIVE)))
#                        ^----this function call is evaluated---^
```

What you want to do is to provide bind with a callback, that is a function object. You can use a closure do do this.

```
def callback(t_start, text):
    def inner():
        t_start.insert(INSERT, text)
    return inner # Return the function

listbox.bind("<Return>", callback(t_start, listbox.get(ACTIVE)) )
#                        ^----this call returns a function----^
#                        Be aware that     ^--this parameter-^ is
#                        still evaluated when the interpreter
#                        evaluates the statement
```

The callback function will be called when the event is triggered.

Comment: This works but it's not reloaded, ie when I change active line in listbox and hit Enter it still inserts the first selected line

Comment: This is what I outlined in the comment.

The parameter listbox.get(ACTIVE) is evaluated when the `callback` function is called, you want to evaluate it when the `inner` function is called - in the body of the `inner` function.
Now you know, I'll let you do that as an exercise :)

Answer (score 1):

Like @ddelemeny said, that function is going to be called as it is written. If your program was structured into classes, you normally wouldn't need to pass an argument, because you can interact with variables directly from the function. However, a simple solution for your case would be using a `lambda` expression, so Python won't call the callback function when the control flow reaches it.

```
listbox.bind("<Return>", lambda e: insert_word(t_start,listbox.get(ACTIVE)))
```

http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm